# If $f(x)=x^2 \lfloor 1/x \rfloor \ \ \ \text{for:} x\neq 0 , \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ \text{for} x=0$

Tags: limits

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function such that:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 \left\lfloor \dfrac 1 x \right\rfloor  & x\neq 0\\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}$$

Then find the value of:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)$$

Comment: where are you stuck? what had you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the derivative everywhere except $ \frac{1}{n} $ for integers $ n $, since the floor function has derivative zero everywhere but integers.

That should be enough to allow you to find the limit.